# Wso2 APIM multi tenancy and keycloak integration

Tags: wso2, keycloak, multi-tenant

I am trying use keycloak as my IDP in wso2 and it works fine when using default admin user (by default blong to carbon domain) but when trying to get authentication token from a user belonging to different domain created using multitenancy domain created I am getting `403 forbidden`.
Wso2 console error

```
Caused by: feign.FeignException$Forbidden: [403 Forbidden] during [POST] to [http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/clients-registrations/openid-connect] [DCRClient#createApplication(ClientInfo)]: [{"error":"insufficient_scope","error_description":"Forbidden"}]
        at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:199) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:177) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:169) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy496.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.wso2.keycloak.client.KeycloakClient.createApplication(KeycloakClient.java:134) ~[keycloak.key.manager_2.0.2.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:150) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:124) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:117) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
        ... 59 more
[2021-01-20 11:21:43,158] ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
```

Keycloak console message

```
11:20:35,757 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-16) type=CLIENT_REGISTER_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=not_allowed
```

[image: Wso2 APIM console error]

[image: Keycloak console error]

Comment: Looks like the user does not have enough scopes.

Comment: I have enabled all the scoped which were enabled for carbon admin user for this new tenant user as well. Using the same keycloak client for carbon admin works through. @Pubci

Comment: @ShyamKumar I am facing exactly same problem. did you manage to resolve this issue ? It would be great helpful if you share any solution that you have. Thanks.